# How to convert Azure pipeline powershell task variable to an array

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a requirement to convert the task variable which was set in one stage(say stage1) to be available in stage two(say stage2), this I am able to achieve. But the problem is this task variable is actually a space separated value and on the basis space I want to convert this into an array, so that I can iterate over each item and perform the business.
I have tried .split that did not worked. Anything I am trying with this variable in stage two, it is actually evaluating to its value. So that is basically causing pipeline to fail.
Please help here how do I convert the task variable to an array.

[image: image of pipeline added here]

Comment: Please show your yaml and powershell script you have so far.

Comment: @jessehouwing image of pipeline added.

Comment: Next time, please add the "screenshot" as text to the post. This is very hard to read and can't be indexed by StackOverflow's search.

Comment: Did you look at the picture you posted? Please don't ever take pictures of the screen with a camera. Learn how to take screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted, just keeping the variable under double quotes worked.